# Name for sayings that are too obvious

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

The saying/idiom/cliche *Winners are grinners* gets my goat and rides it into a brick wall. It's just too obvious. All it has going for it is the rhyme. Is there a term for a saying that is just too obvious and self-evident?

Comment: Isn’t that the definition of a cliché?

Answer (score 2):

I can do no better than commend Merriam Webster to you. I started there with one of my favourites - "*hackneyed*" - and discovered several old friends:

"Choose the Right Synonym for hackneyed - TRITE, HACKNEYED, STEREOTYPED, THREADBARE mean lacking the freshness that evokes attention or interest.

TRITE applies to a once effective phrase or idea spoiled from long familiarity.  "you win some, you lose some" is a trite expression

HACKNEYED stresses being worn out by overuse so as to become dull and meaningless.  all of the metaphors and images in the poem are hackneyed

STEREOTYPED implies falling invariably into the same pattern or form.  views of minorities that are stereotyped and out-of-date

THREADBARE applies to what has been used until its possibilities of interest have been totally exhausted.  a mystery novel with a threadbare plot"

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hackneyed)

Comment: What Im looking for is a word that describes a saying, cliche or trite/hackneyed/stereotyped/threadbare phrase that is lame from the get-go. Something  like 'nafforism', perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I had difficulty - and still have it - in finding anything like “threadbare non-starter”. The lack of answers suggests others have similar difficulty. Perhaps there is no such word and the time has come for a neologism. If so, something like *nafforism*  has its charms.